# como puedo quitar el error de "array lower bounds can be only '0' error"?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Dim Vec1(1 To 50) As Integer
Dim Vec2(1 To 50) As Integer
Dim Vec3(1 To 50) As Integer
```

[image: VB]

El uno me lo marca como

> Array lower bounds can be only '0' error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En .NET (y practicamente en todos los lenguajes actuales), los arrays son "0-based", es decir, el indice inferior empieza en 0. No se para que necesitas que el array empiece en 1, pero te recomiendo que te acostumbres a trabajar con Arrays que empiezan en 0, ya que es el standard y cualquier programador que pueda utilizar tu código siempre esperará que sea asi.

Dicho esto, hay una manera de declarar Arrays en VB.net con un límite inferior diferente a 0, aunque de verdad no te recomiendo que lo utilices:

```
Dim Vec1 As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Integer), New Integer() {50}, New Integer() {1})
```

Debes tener en cuenta que aunque está definido como array, en realidad es un tipo diferente asi que por ejemplo no te dejará asignarlo a un array normal, y es posible que te de algun problema al pasarlo a un método dependiendo del tipo que este espere recibir.